How to tweak geom_text element in sjPlot
I use this code:
library(sjPlot)

mtcars |> 
  plot_frq(cyl)

and I get

I would like to remove the parentheses and round the percentage numbers to the nearest whole number. So that I get 34% instead of (34.4%). I am looking for a direct way to access the ggplot elements.
I tried accessing the underlying ggplot object but was unsuccessful.
Thank you very much!

Looking at the source code of plot_frq the number of decimal places and the parentheses are hard-coded in: https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/blob/19d846b809c0ab86955812b594bdf68869134361/R/plot_frq.R#L455 . Seems like it would be easier to just write your own code to make the plot you want rather than trying to modify the plot_frq output

I agree with @qdread that it might be easier to build the plot from scratch. But if you want to do the hacky approach then one option would be to get rid of the labels added by plot_frq and add your own:
library(sjPlot)
library(ggplot2)

p <- mtcars |>
  plot_frq(cyl)

p$layers[[2]]$aes_params$label <- NULL

p +
  aes(label = paste(
    .data$frq,
    scales::percent(.data$frq / sum(.data$frq), accuracy = 1),
    sep = "\n"
  ))


